# ModuleNotFoundError for ibm-watson-machine-learning package

Tags: python, pip, ibm-cloud, modulenotfounderror

I entered following command in my jupyter notebook: `!pip install -U ibm-watson-machine-learning` and with I can see the package install with `!pip list`.

But when I try to import like so: `import ibm_watson_machine_learning`, I get following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_watson_machine_learning'`.

Comment: if you run Python 3 then it may need `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: **SOLVED**: For me, I simply needed to update all my packages in conda with ```conda upgrade --all```, still thanks for your contribution @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** For me, I simply needed to update all my packages in conda with `conda upgrade --all`.